# Adding help text to drupal comment form

Tags: comments

using Drupal 7, I'd like to add some help text underneath each field for the user who is filling out the comment for a node.

For example, under 'your name' I'd like it to say, possibly in smaller font, "only give your name if you want it published with your comment".

Anyone know how to do this (maybe with hook_form_alter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in hook_form_alter, you need to check the $form_id first, so that you can target comment form. If it is a comment form, then you need to add description for the field you want. Just like this

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

$form['name']['#description'] = t('Me help text'),
```

`}`

Answer (score 2):

Or just edit comment.tpl.php in your template files. Copy comment.tpl.php to your template folder and if not present in the code, add $author name and desired text.